# Retrieve values from shared service

Tags: angular

When trying to retrieve values from my shared service I am getting this in my console

```
ƒ (CustomerAccountDocs) {
        return this.customerAccountDocs = CustomerAccountDocs;
    }
```

Do I possibly need to subscribe to it or something?

As it stands I am simply assigning service to a variable

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.customerAccountDocs = this.CustomerAccountDocsService.customerAccountDocs_share;
    console.log(this.customerAccountDocs)
  }
```

My service looks like this

```
  customerAccountDocs_share(CustomerAccountDocs:[]) {
    return this.customerAccountDocs = CustomerAccountDocs;
  }
```

I am setting the value that the service function should return here.

```
  getCustomerAccountDocs(selectedItem: any, index: number) {
    this.CustomerAccountDocsService.getCustomerAccountDocs()
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.CustomerAccountDocsService.customerAccountDocs_share = data._embedded.deliveryMessageList;
    });
  }
```

Comment: can you post the code to `CustomerAccountDocsService.customerAccountDocs_share`?

Comment: yes, I have updated in question

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any `Observable` that needs subscribing in your code. One important thing though is that you're *logging* a function in `console.log(this.customerAccountDocs)`.

Try replacing that with this

```
const arr = [];
console.log(this.customerAccountDocs(arr));
```

That will actually print what the function returns, although we're passing an empty array here. I didn't really understand what intention is from your code, but this gets the value return by the function you have called.

Comment: ok I see, so what I was trying to do is get the value being returned by the service function. I have updated the question to show where the value is being set

Comment: yes, I saw that edit. The answer still holds, that if you want to get the actual value returned, you need to call the function

Comment: ok, I thought the last function in my question was setting the value and the ngOninit code was getting the value back. I'll need to see how the service actually works.